# Alternative to gets?

Tags: c, fgets, gets

I used to use gets but then I heard that it got removed from c11 and that its overall very dangerous.
So I did some searching and found out that you can use fgets() to do the same thing.

The problems is that when I do use fgets() it seems to also copy the end of the line aswell, which ends up making an extra unwanted line.

To show you what I mean:

```
//if I have 
char key[30];
fgets(key, sizeof(key), stdin);

//now if ender for instance: Doggo and do:
printf("The key is:%s|hozaah!\n", key);

//I expect it to print:
The key is:Doggo|hozaah!

//Instead it prints:
The key is:Doggo
|hozaah!
```

Is there a way to get around this? Or is there another function I can use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard direct replacement for `gets()`, but there are many easy ways to get rid of the newline if present:

- The simplest using `strcspn` (declared in `<string.h>`):

  ```
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
      buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
  }
  ```
- The classic using `strlen`:

  ```
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
      size_t len = strlen(buf);
      if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n')
          buf[--len] = '\0';
  }
  ```
- Another classic with `strchr`:

  ```
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
      char *p = strchr(buf, '\n');
      if (p != NULL)
          *p = '\0';
  }
  ```

An alternative is the POSIX function `getline()` which might be available on your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

The buffer is allocated or reallocated with `malloc()` and its size is updated into `*n`. The initial values should be `lineptr = NULL` and `n = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the fact that `fgets` reads as many characters as fit into the buffer, including a null terminator, but only up to end of file or a newline, and it will *store the newline* in the string, too: [`man 3 fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html)

So if you enter input on the terminal, the newline is transmitted to the standard input, too, and read by `fgets`. This is different from the old `gets`, which replaces the newline with a null byte.

So if you're reading lines and don't want the potential newline, strip it out. Unfortunately, `fgets` does not tell you how many characters were read, so you have to scan the string again to work it out:

```
char* p = fgets(key, sizeof(key), stdin);

if (!p) { /* error */ }

size_t n = strlen(key);

if (n > 0 && key[n - 1] == '\n') {
  key[n - 1] = '\0';
} else {
  /* buffer too short or EOF reached without newline */
}

printf("The line was: '%s'\n", key);
```

It may be worth considering alternatives: If you only need one input, don't input the newline in the first place. If you need lots of lines, use  `fread` into a fixed-size buffer and scan for newlines yourself.

Comment: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AwlDxatyy7fnSuXF), try it with and without input newline.